# How to request a Node.js code execution on the client side?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I have an *Ionic Framework* app (v1) and a **Node.js** file that executes some functions to a credit-card API I'm using. I've been testing the execution of the node file with the following command on terminal:

```
$ node file.js
```

And it works perfectly with my local machine. The problem is that I'll use my app for production soon, so how can I run this *server-side* code after a button click event in my *front-end* app ? Do I need to store this node file in the server and access it with angular http service ? How can I trigger the execution remotely?

I'm currently using Firebase as my *back-end*.

I've been struggling with this for days and I'm pretty new to Node.js. Please help me.

Comment: Yes, the $http service is the normal way to communicate with server based code (exposed via REST or web sockets).  You could also use firebase to do the communication.  You could write a message to a firebase node, and have the server side code listen for changes.

Comment: See, [Building serverless web application with Angular, Webtask and Firebase](http://codewithstyle.info/building-serverless-web-application-angular-2-webtask-firebase/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of architecture and best practices, I recommend you to create an NodeJS API application and your Ionic app will make request to this API. You need to define route(s) to your NodeJS app, put it in production to provide Ionic app to send requests to its route(s).

As you sad that is a simple function, look at [Express](http://expressjs.com/) that is a NodeJS framework. The [routing guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) shows how to create a simple route using this framework.

To summarize, your Ionic app will send requests to NodeJS API route and this route will execute some functions to your credit card API.

Comment: That helped me a lot. Now I have a NodeJS API running on Heruko, and my app sends requests to it, like you said. Even though the credit-card API that I'm using (GerenciaNet) takes care about all the data security, should I worry about security too? Since I'm posting data to the API I created on Heruko. Thanks, by the way!